# Как получить список вещей из инвентаря Unity Steam?

Tags: c#, steam

На C# необходимо получить список вещей в инверторе Steam. Для получения пытался использовать Stemworks API и Facepunch Stemworks. 
Вот попытки получить название предметов в инверторе.

```
SteamInventoryResult_t steam;
    SteamInventory.GetAllItems(out steam);
    uint size = 0;
    SteamItemDetails_t []steamItemDetails_T=new SteamItemDetails_t[size];
    SteamItemDef_t steamItemDef_T=new SteamItemDef_t();
    string invent; 
    SteamInventory.GetItemDefinitionProperty(steamItemDef_T, "name"  ,out invent,ref size);
    Debug.Log(invent);
```

Предметы в инверторе есть но он выдает что их 0 и соответственно вы дает результат NULL

Comment: Судя по вопросу не пытались. Только узнали, что это реализуется через Stemworks API и всё. Читайте документацию, она есть полностью на русском.

Comment: Пытался но название предметов так и не вывелось

Answer (score 0):

Я с Stemworks API дел не имел, но `m_itemId` вроде как [Глобальный уникальный дескриптор экземпляра предмета](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamInventory). А тебе нужен `name`, который с свою очередь содержит `name_english`, `name_french`  и т.д. [ItemDef Properties](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/inventory/schema)
.

Comment: Выдает результат NULL хотя к игре подкючается